# Override of OnActionExecuting and a .ashx file upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onactionexecuting

I have a MVC project that uses a 3rd party upload .ashx page. I also have the following override for OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
   SessionContext context = (SessionContext)filterContext.HttpContext.Session[SessionConstants.SessionContext];

   if (context == null || context.Ticket == null) {
       filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(TimeoutRedirectUrl);
       return;
   }

   base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

This is here to make sure users are still logged in when they visit MVC pages. However, after a user uploads a file it looks like the "context" is null and then OnActionExecuting() redirects the user.

Why would there no longer be a context after a user uploads a file? I want them to still be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a controller action method to upload the file instead of the generic handler? Handlers are very low level and by default have no access to cookies, session, etc.

Comment: I guess that's the direction I should head in as I think it would solve a lot of problems. I'm only using a handler because the guy that worked on this project before me did. I wanted to try and make it work without a lot or rewriting but I don't think that's going to happen.